# Qt - C++ - fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'afx.h'

Tags: c++, qt, twain

Here I describe the steps I followed to try to build the following C++ project:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/files/TWAIN%202%20Sample%20Application/

On a Microsoft Windows 7 - 64 bit. My ultimate goal is to keep the functionality and to add command-line parameters so I can run it in a batch file, because right now, it's a menu-based software.

1. **Installation of Qt Creator Community**

   - Version 3.5.0 (based on Qt 5.5.0 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)
   - Kits available:

     - Desktop Qt 5.4.2 MSVC2013 64bit2
     - Desktop Qt 5.5.0 MSVC2010 32bit
     - Desktop Qt 5.5.0 MSVC2012 32bit
     - Desktop Qt 5.5.0 MSVC2013 32bit
     - Desktop Qt 5.5.0 MSVC2013 64bit
2. **Downloading Freeimage library (binary)**

   - http://downloads.sourceforge.net/freeimage/FreeImage3170Win32Win64.zip
3. **Installing Freeimage library**

   - Uncompress **FreeImage3170Win32Win64.zip**
   - open the folder **FreeImage\Dist\x64**
   - Copy **freeimage.dll** in the **C:\Windows\System32** folder
4. **Downloading and uncompressing Twain project**

   - Download **Twain_App_sample.source.zip** in http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/files/TWAIN%202%20Sample%20Application/
   - Uncompress the archive **Twain_App_sample.source.zip**, that gives the 2 following folders:

     - **Twain_App_sample01**
     - **common**
5. **Putting Freeimage header file and lib in the project**

   - copy **Freeimage.h** in the **common** folder
   - create a **lib** folder in **Twain_App_sample01\src** folder
   - copy **freeimage.lib** in **Twain_App_sample01\src\lib** folder
6. **Configuration of the project in Qt Creator**

   - launch **Qt Creator**
   - in Qt, click **Open project**
   - choose the file **src.pro** in the **Twain_App_sample01\src** folder
   - in ***Configure Project*** choose the Kit **Desktop Qt 5.5.0 MSVC2013 64bit**
   - click the **Configure project** button
7. **Create and use a string conversion function**

   - in **DSMInterface.cpp** source file, add this function:

     ```
     wchar_t *convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(const char* charArray)
     {
         wchar_t* wString=new wchar_t[4096];
         MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, charArray, -1, wString, 4096);
         return wString;
     }
     ```
   - in **DSMInterface.cpp**, function **LoadDSMLib**, replace

     ```
     if((gpDSM=LOADLIBRARY(_pszLibName)) != 0)
     ```

     with

     ```
     if((gpDSM=LOADLIBRARY(convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(_pszLibName))) != 0)
     ```
8. **Compilation - part 1**

   - Now i get a message from the linker:

> `DSMInterface.obj:-1: error : LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl VerifyEmbeddedSignature(wchar_t const *)" (?VerifyEmbeddedSignature@@YAHPEB_W@Z) referenced in function "bool __cdecl LoadDSMLib(char *)" (?LoadDSMLib@@YA_NPEAD@Z)`

I added the **Twain_App_sample01\src\VerifySignature.cpp** file to the project and now this message is gone (thanks to **Itay Grudev** for this)

9. **Compilation - part 2**

   - I have another message now

> `..\src\VerifySignature.cpp(13) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'afx.h': No such file or directory`

Comment: From the [Twain Forum](http://twainforum.org) `You need to include the VerifySignature.cpp source file. Depending on your OS you may need to comment out the following variable WinTrustData.dwUIContext = 0;`

Comment: It looks like it uses MFC. Do you have MFC installed? It's not part of the Community edition of Visual Sudio.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I was starting with the Wrong tool. Thanks to **Ben** who sent me on the right track. I needed MFC.
So The right solution is to use Visual Studio 2015.
I could build it with that.